# MemoryError zipfile in memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-s3, stringio, python-zipfile

I'm getting `MemoryError (out of memory)` when zipping files in memory with Python. I'm using cStringIO.StringIO as an in memory buffer stream. Follow the code below:

```
    zip_file = cStringIO.StringIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file=zip_file, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        for f in files:
            zf.writestr(f.file_name, f.get_data())
        for f in images:
            try:
                zf.writestr(str(f.name), f.read())
            except:
                pass

    files_email.append({
        'clinic_name': clinic.name,
        'url': send_to_s3(zip_file, file_name, 60 * 60 * 48),
    })
    zip_file.close()
```

Any idea on how can I fix it?

Comment: what are in files and images? Have you tried closing the files as you iterate?

Comment: There are `csv.writer` and `xlwt.Workbook` instances, bytes instances. In images are `ImageFieldFile ` Django instances.

Comment: How large are we talking in terms of data size?

Comment: around 100MB, its not so big.